# Unable to start mysql after changing replicate do table on master

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Master was running with the following:

```
server-id=1
log-bin = /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysql_bin.log
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database
```

I thought I could just simply change to:

```
log-bin = /opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysql_bin2.log
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database2
```

And just restart mysql, but instead got an error:

```
[ERROR] Could not add do table rule 'my_database2'
```

I tried changing back to the old settings, but that failed to start as well. What did I do wrong and what should I have done? How do I fix this now?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify both, the table name and the database name separating them with a period.

A particular database and a particular table:

```
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database2.my_table1
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database2.my_table2
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database2.my_table3
```

A wildcard pattern as a table name:

```
replicate-wild-do-table=my_database2.my_table%
```

Read more: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table